# "ScrollView can host only one direct child" only in Landscape mode

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to use ScrollView and it works fine in Portrait mode but doesn't in Landscape mode. When I start the app, everything's fine but when I turn my phone on the side I have the "ScrollView can host only one direct child" Exception.

Here is my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/content_show_details_fragment_picture"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/boiler_room"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:alpha="0.8"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/content_show_details_fragment_title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Titre de l'émission"
                android:layout_above="@+id/content_show_details_fragment_subtitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subtitle"
                android:id="@+id/content_show_details_fragment_subtitle"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Prochaine diffusion"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/content_show_details_fragment_date"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="11/11/2014 à 18h00"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Podcasts"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/content_show_details_fragment_listView"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the Exceptions :

```
11-25 21:21:57.289  17419-17419/com.readyo.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.readyo.app, PID: 17419
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.readyo.app/com.readyo.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
            at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:387)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:901)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5460)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you using different layouts for different orientations?

Comment: you have another issue, the linearlayout inside the scroll view, should not be heigth=match_parent, should be wrap_content or a fixed size or whatever, cause if not, you will not be able to scroll.

Comment: Nope I'm using the same layout for both orientations. Also as Jorge suggested, I change the parameter to wrap_content, but I'm still getting the error...

Comment: Are you trying to use this layout with a Fragment or directly in an Activity? I wonder if you are inadvertently holding onto an instance of a view hierarchy before the activity is restarted on the orientation change. Does the same issue occur if you start the app in landscape then change to portrait?

Comment: Are you programmatically adding views to the ScrollView?

Comment: Marcus.ramsden made a first step I think. I'm using a fragment. When I'm in landscape mode, in my Navigation drawer I clic on the item to go to that fragment, this works fine, and when I turn my phone in portrait the Exception is thrown.

I don't add any View in the ScrollView, I only affect them programmatically.

Comment: I tried to block the change of orientation in the manifest with the line : android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize".
This didn't blocked the orientation (cause I forgot to add : android:screenOrientation="portrait") but it solve my first problem. I don't think this is very clean but that worked...
If you have any idea why, I'm interested !